# Firebase Cloud Messaging - test message not sending

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I generated the token using `final fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();` and put it in the console, then selected it and sent the test message, but nothing showed up on my phone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out - these notifications only appear when the app is in the background. I clicked the home button on my phone then sent the test notification and it showed up.

Comment: Do you find out why it behaves that way?

Comment: @W00di I think this is the default behavior